# how to prevent recreat new Fragment again and again?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-tablayout

Hello I made simple program in Android in which i take 3 Tabs in tablayout  When i click on 1st Tab it opens first Fragment but when i goes to second Tab then again come to First TAb select  It recreate and  Overlapp my new Fragment...now how to Stop that??

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tablayout);
    tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("One"), true);
    tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Two"), false);

    tabLayout.setOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {                                                      
            @Override
        public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
            if (tab.getPosition() == 0) {
                Fragment fragment = new Fragment1();

                chageFragment(fragment);
            } 

        }

        @Override
        public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

        }
    });

  }

private void chageFragment(Fragment fragment) {
     getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.container,    fragment,fragment.getClass().getSimpleName()).commit();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try change this line to use `replace` instead of `add`.

```
getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.container, fragment, fragment.getClass().getSimpleName()).commit();
```

Should be

```
getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container, fragment, fragment.getClass().getSimpleName()).commit();
```

Comment: Thanks for response. i changed method add to replace. it solve overlapping but when i clicked on tab 2 and tab 3 also show tab1's fragment ..

Answer (score 0):

If you want the fragment to not be recreated then you should use a view pager. It can be used as tabs and the fragments are not recreated nor do they overlap. If you want to solve the overlap issue then Kevin here has given the correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

Use replace instead of add method it will solve your problem.

getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container,    fragment,fragment.getClass().getSimpleName()).commit();

Comment: Thanks for response. i changed method add to replace. it solve overlapping but when i clicked on tab 2 and tab 3 also show tab1's fragment ..